# Creating a workspace on IBM Watson lite

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to create a workspace.
Will create a chatbot using Watson Assistant.
The tutorial I'm referring to is for Watson Conversation.
Can you point me where to look - it's just a different interface.
Thanks,

G

Comment: Watson Conversaion was the old name for Watson Assistant.  Workspaces are now called skills.

Answer (score 0):

A workspace is now called a Skill. So click the Skills tab next to the home page and click create new.

There is a tutorial inside the Watson Assistant documentation that is continually kept up to date that may be easier to follow.